# Dropdown menu collide with an image

Tags: html, css

I've created a simple CSS drop down menu, problem is that I have a image gallery and when I hover on the menu on the area where the image is the image takes the focus and not the menu.
Any advice how to solve it? Z-Index maybe?

[Here is the problematic page](http://ogjewels.co.il/content/galleries/amulets/goldfilled/galleryPage1.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#nav ul li {z-index: 9;}
```

seems to work.

Comment: That worked! Thanks, can you provide bit of explanation why 9 solved that?

Comment: It doesn't need to be 9 specifically; I just chose a number that I thought would be higher than any other z-index properties you might have specified already in your css. It just needs to be higher than whatever your other properties are.

Answer (score 1):

z-index definitely.

```
#menu{
  z-index: 2;
}

#gallery{
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I've also noticed your utilizing large amounts of opacity. when two semi-transparent elements overlap, both of their colors will be affected.

tip: try using a thumbnail genertor for those images, they take a while to load

Good Luck!
-Brian

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, only 2 there are for some reason really big. Thanks for the tip.